# Принудительный вызов base C#

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Какая в  C# есть возможность для принудительного вызова функции базового класса  в функции наследника

Пример:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void F(){...}
}

class B : A
{
    public override void F()
    {
       base.F();//<--- должна быть эта строка! Иначе ,
                //выкинуть ошибку, к примеру. 
        ...
    }
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: нет, родного способа заставить вызвать метод базового класса нет. Можно придумать какой-нибудь трюк с флагами... А зачем это вам? Опишите задачу подробнее

Comment: Смотрите паттерн проектирования "Шаблонный метод" - Template method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Можно сделать так: порядок вызова определяем в родителе, а наследников обязуем переопределить их часть. Если эта часть необязательная, то можно ослабить условие, и сделать метод `virtual` вместо `abstract`.

```
class A
{
    public void F()
    {
        // базовый код

        FInternal();
    }

    protected abstract void FInternal();

    // более мягкий вариант
    //protected virtual void FInternal()
    //{
    //}
}

class B : A
{
    protected override void FInternal()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Опередили на минуту :)

Answer (score 4):

Наследованием вы не добьетесь. Сделайте из базового класса сервис, которому передавайте клиентский класс, чтобы он находился под управлением сервиса:

```
interface IClient() {
    void F();
}

class Service : IClient {

    public void Execute(IClient c) {
        F();
        c.F();
    }

    public void F() { ... }
};
```

Comment: То есть по сути композиция вместо наследования? Хорошая идея.