# Почему вызов базового метода из переопределяемого считается Best Practice?

Tags: c#

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему обязательно надо вызывать базовый метод, согласно ООП/SOLID/и т.д.?

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Do()
    {
        // some logic
    }
}

class Child : Base
{
    public override void Do()
    {
        base.Do(); // <- обязательный вызов?
        // some additional logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Не обязательно, кто сказал что обязательно?

Comment: Не обязательно, но, в целом принято, потому что наследник не должен изменять уже существующее базовое поведение. В базовом методе может быть запрограммирована некая важная функциональность, например, в WinForms методы контролов вида On... (OnClick, OnLoad, OnClose) вызывают обработчики событий, если Вы не вызовите базовый метод событие просто не выстрелит. Также при реализации базовых классов в проекте в них может быть заложена некая инфраструктурная функциональность, такая, как, например, запись в лог. Почитайте о принципах SOLID, применительно к Вашему вопросу, Вас интересуют принципы L и O.

Comment: Да, и не делайте виртуальные методы публичными, только `protected`. А публичными методами оборачивайте вызовы виртуальных.

Comment: @Bulson Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить свою позицию по поводу виртуальных методов? Почему их никогда не стоит делать public?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko инкапсуляция, open/close, принцип Лисков тому причиной. Хотя если вы делаете какую-то библиотеку API для использования другими и разрешаете наследование от ваших классов, то в этом случае возможно сделать методы публичными.

Comment: @Bulson Хочу, но пока не могу понять, как это нарушает принципы, которые вы перечислили. Вот есть абстрактный класс со своим набором методов и среди них - виртуальный метод. Если сделать этот метод protected, то он пропадет из "интерфейса" базового класса (мы не сможем его вызвать). Получается, у наследников будет этот метод, а тот, кто будет использовать базовый класс, не будет знать о нем. Зачем так делать?

Comment: Не совсем так выразился. Если есть цель сделать доступным переписанный (override) виртуальный метод базового класса, то зачем писать `public` - методы для доступа к `protected override` методам наследника, если просто можно сделать сами `override` методы публичными?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko [Нужно ли виртуальные методы объявлять как protected?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749392/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за ссылку! обязательно взгляну, когда появится время. Нужно вникнуть, быстрого просмотра не хватило для полного понимания.